# Using variable images with django-webodt

Tags: django, image, libreoffice, odt

Is anyone using [django-webodt](https://github.com/NetAngels/django-webodt)? Looking through the documentation, I can't find anything about using images in a document. I want to insert "variable" images (ImageField) in my ODT document. Is this possible?

I'm using the OpenOffice backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is a solution for you, I use [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) in my projects with nice results, I have never tested to include images but it is documented:

[Quoting pod doc](http://appyframework.org/podWritingAdvancedTemplates.html):

[image]

> **Integrating external files or images into the result: the document function**
>
> The document function allows you to integrate, into the ODT result,
>   images or files that come from external sources. Here is the function
>   signature; the table below explains each parameter.

**EDITED DUE OP COMMENT**

I come to test it and work pretty well, also into loops. Here you can see python (or django) rendering document with images:

```
>>> from appy.pod.renderer import Renderer
>>> taula1 = [1,2,3]
>>> taula = [ taula1, taula1 ]
>>> renderer = Renderer('report.odt',  globals(), 'result.odt')
>>> renderer.run()
```

ODT:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works with images but unfortunately it doesn't support nested loops nor spanning the values of one record in the loop over more than one table-rows.

Comment: Crazy that's cool. Is there also a way to change the backgroundcolor of a cell based on its value?

Comment: Is there also a way to change the backgroundcolor of a cell based on its value?
Thanks for your help

Comment: @RobertDollinger, write new post for new question. It is interesting, perhaps some user has been tested it, if not, I will digging docs to solve it.